# How to replace Null value of a particular row and column to 'Other'

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I have the below data with some Null values.

[image]

Now my requirement is I'm looking for a code where I would like to replace particular row of a particular column to **Other**. I would like to see the output as below.

[image]

As you can see row 3 of Gender column has been replaced with **Other**.

Regards,

Bharath Vikas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for `.at[]` here:

```py
df.at[3, 'Gender'] = 'Other'
```

This will allow you to reference a single cell, by its index and column name (in this order).

Read here: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.at.html

If instead of a single cell you wish to reference a range do:

```py
df.loc[df['Gender'].fillna('').eq(''), 'Gender'] = 'Other'
```

This will modify all rows in `Gender` with empty `Gender`.

Read here: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html#pandas.DataFrame.loc

Comment: Thanks for your help, both the codes worked really well for me.